# MYSQL: What is the benefit of compound indexes, over separate ones?

Tags: mysql, index

I've been experimenting with the performance of SELECT queries on a table with about a million records, consisting of these columns(among others..):

```
id, lastName, firstName,
```

Wehn i perform this query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `user` 
WHERE lastName = 'someLastName' 
AND firstName = 'someFirstName'
```

I get more or less the same performance(in terms of miliseconds), whether i have **two separate indexes on those fields, or have a compound index(lastName,firstName).**

I came across this thread:[difference between creating index with two columns and creating separate index on two columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24567887/difference-between-creating-index-with-two-columns-and-creating-separate-index-o)

The guy explains the case where a compound index might fall short, bu he didn't give any example where it can actually be beneficial, over setting up separate indexes.

Can someone provide an example/simple explanation of a scenario where a compound index is a good choice?

Comment: E.g. `select ... WHERE lastName = 'someLastName' 
ORDER BY firstName`.

Comment: `I get more or less the same performance(in terms of miliseconds)` how many rows are we talking about?

Comment: There are about a million rows, and two results for the query(the first column, "lastName", has only about 300 hits, so maybe this is why the performance is similar)

Answer (score 4):

If you know that you frequently query on a combination of fields, a combined index means "you only have to search one B-tree."  Otherwise, the server would have to search *n* individual B-trees and then combine the results.

*(N.B.:  A "B-tree" is a data structure commonly used by database servers to create indexes ...)*

(You can use the `EXPLAIN` command to quickly see how the server plans to do this ... and to see that it *does* have to do this.)

Comment: "...to search n individual B-trees" -- I would add that each one of these searches can be painfully slow (or fast) depending on the index. The execution plan will tell you.

Answer (score 3):

I think MySQL has a good [explanation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/multiple-column-indexes.html) of how composite indexes are used.

If your queries only take a few milliseconds, then indexes are probably not needed.  One use of indexes is to reduce the number of data pages that need to be read.  If you have only one data page for a table, there is not much utility there.

So, I think the answer to your question is that you need many thousands of rows in your table to see a big improvement in performance when using indexes for filtering.  Your data is probably not big enough.  Yet.

Comment: Clarification: i have a million rows, which is quite a lot i think. The indexes, in both cases(composite or not), provide a significant improvement over a query where no indexes are present on those columns(i've experimented with all possibilities). What i wanted to stress, is that both with composite and separate indexes- i get very similar performance.

Answer (score 1):

The ultimate answer here probably depends on whatever `EXPLAIN` is telling you for this query, for the two index strategies (separate vs. compound).  In general, if you have an index only on one of the name fields in the `WHERE` clause, MySQL won't use either of the indices.  It might be possible for it to use both indices, but that would be unlikely.  On the other hand, an index on `(lastName, firstName)` at the very least does cover the `WHERE` clause (though not the `SELECT` clause), and so should be a candidate for MySQL to use.  If MySQL is really not using the compound index, then you should check `EXPLAIN` to find out why.

One possible explanation why the compound index would not be used is if your table size be fairly small.  In that case, MySQL might choose to just do a full table scan and not use any index at all.  Another explanation for why the compound index would not be used is the cardinality of your data.  Specifically, if the first and last names repeat very often, and you are searching for a common pair, then adding an index might not add much benefit over just doing a full table scan.

Comment: WOW is sql complicated :D I'll make experiments with EXPLAIN

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is perhaps the analogy with a phone book (remember those?).

A phone book for a city is typically indexed on lastname, firstname. Imagine a phone book for a city of 1 million people.

If you're looking for "John Smith", you go to the "Smith" section; this reduces the number of possible hits from 1 million to perhaps a few thousand. You can then jump to the "Smith, John" section; that reduces the few thousand to a handful. The biggest saving is by jumping from "1 million names" to "a few thousand Smiths". The additional saving of searching for "John" is much smaller.

So, the compound index (lastname, firstname) is probably faster than "lastname" alone, but on modern hardware, searching a few thousand "Smiths" is indeed milliseconds (if you can measure it at all).

If you repeated your query with something less selective, but still affected by the index, you will probably see a bigger difference.

```
SELECT * 
FROM `user` 
WHERE lastName like 's*' 
AND firstName = 'j*'
```

Comment: Yes, i think this is the case here, because the lastName search narrows the results down to about 300, where it would be very quick to find a desired firstName. I'll make some example where lastName brings 100k results, and then see :D